# Can I create type template for nested json object with dynamic property key with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typing

I am new to typescript and new to javascript. I am required to create this type of structure with json objects inside array:

```js
[
  {
    dynamic_proerty_name: {
      array_A: [],
      array_B: [],
    },
  },
  ...
];
```

There are one to many objects. All objects have different `dynamic_proerty_name` (they are unique).

The way i've implemented this now is creating type as such:

```js
type Lists = {
  "array_A": string[];
  "array_B": string[];
};

// Create one object
let lists = {
  "array_A": [];
  "array_B": [];
};
let obj = {
  [dynamic_property_name]: lists,
};
```

Problem raises when I want to pass this datatype into function as parameter. I can set:

```js
function foo(data: any[]) {
  ...
}
```

but as I understand it is unwise to use `any[]` as a type. I would like to set the exact type, but cant seem to figure it out. I've tried to to print these at runtime:

```js
typeof data              // returns: object
data.constructor.name    // returns: Array
data[0].constructor.name // returns: Object
typeof data[0]           // returns: object
```

I've tried `Object[]` and `object[]` as type, but it gives me error everytime.

Now I would figure that possible solutions would be to define `Lists` type again so that it would contain also the dynamic property, but I am uncertain if:
a) that is possible
b) that would solve my primary problem.

Comment: You might want to use `{[k: string]: Lists}` aka `Record<string, Lists>` for the type of `obj`, but without seeing a [mre] involving use cases it's hard to be sure.  Right now you're not doing anything inside of `foo` so I'm not sure what you intend to do with `data`.  Nor are you using your `Lists` type or the `obj` value more than once.  Could you provide a more clear code example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for input. I indend to push strings to `array_A` and `array_B` in `foo()`. In practice there are more that one pair of those arrays. This is assignement and thus the format. I couldn't find any documantation of `Record` other that it would be "upcoming" feature (obviously release has passed if you propose it). Could you please point me to the documantation?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type